# Project Euler - 1: Finding multiples of 3 and 5

Tags: c#

Project Euler - Problem 1: Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

Looking through the questions here about the same problem I assume the way I tried to solve is is quite bad.  What is the best way to solve this?

And my other question:  The sum value doesn't match the answer. I think the problem is that when I use `foreach` to write out the list value its starts from 705 instead of 3, but I have no idea why. I would appreciate if someone could explain it to me.

This is the code that I'm using now:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
for (int i = 3; i < 1000; i += 3)
{
    numbers.Add(i);
}
for (int j = 5; j < 1000; j += 5)
{
    numbers.Add(j);
}
numbers.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
int sum1 = numbers.Sum();
Console.WriteLine(sum1);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Make end much smaller (i.e. 16 instead of 1000) and look at the output.

Comment: This is from Project Euler? I have a great solution to this on my website: fixbyproximity.com under misc and euler. I cannot directly link it because I am at work and they block my site. Check it out though, it goes through a couple different ways to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and for all the different solutions :)

Comment: Yes its from PE, thanks for the link

Comment: "What is the best way to solve this?" - [Constant time solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3374682/21727).

Answer (score 4):

This is because `numbers` allows duplicates. Note that you are going to have some duplicates, there - for example, numbers 15, 30, 45, and so on, will be added twice.

Replace

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
```

with

```
ISet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>();
```

and it's going to work because a `HashSet` won't allow duplicate values.

Comment: It doesn't work, the sum value is 60 this way.

Comment: my bad, i changed 1000 to 16 and didn't notice :) thanks for the answer

Answer (score 4):

This is the first problem on [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=1).

Personally, I used a one liner :

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Where(n => n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0).Sum()
```

But you can also use the long way for more readability :

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0))
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
}
```

If you don't know how the modulo (%) operator works, I suggest you read it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

If you need more details about the problem itself, just create an account on Project Euler, enter the answer, and read the [Problem Overview](http://projecteuler.net/overview=001).

Answer (score 3):

You're not accounting for numbers that are both multiples of 3 **and** 5

If I were you, I'd have something like the following

```
for(int i=1; i<1000; i++)
{
    if(i is a multiple of 15)
        //account for 15
    else if(i is a multiple of 3)
        //account for 3
    else if(i is a multiple of 5)
        //account for 5
}
```

Comment: `( (i is a multiple of 3) || (i is a multiple of 5) )` would be probably better.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you're probably right.  I was thinking about the fizzbuzz problem when i did this

Answer (score 3):

The reason your output starts with 705 is because your list of numbers is quite long (532 numbers to be exact). Your Console window can only contain a couple of lines before it starts scrolling.

So you do start with the number 3, it's just not visible.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the issue is that your code counts multiples of 15 twice. Of course, this task is pretty easy using Linq's [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) and [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) methods:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
                        .Where(n => n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0);
foreach(var n in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}

var sum = numbers.Sum();
Console.WriteLine(sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate values in the list. Thats why total sum is invalid. You better change the Data Structure to HashSet which not allow duplicates.

If you can't do that or you have to proceed with this way, try below

call `numbers = numbers.Distinct().ToList();` before `numbers.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

> I think the problem is that when I use foreach to write out the list
>   value its starts from 705 instead of 3, but I have no idea why.

Problem is duplicate values, foreach will print correctly but you may not able to scroll console to beginning of printing.

try `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numbers));`

Comment: While that'd work, you probably want to avoid generating the duplicates to begin with, or to get rid of them earlier than that.  The simple solution is to use a more appropriate data structure than a list.

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve it with Linq. Use `Enumerable.Range` to get all numbers between 0 and 999 (inclusive). Then use `Where` to filter those out which are divisible by 3 *or* divisible by 5. Finally use `Sum`.